Run 2 transforms on 1 snippet in VSCode
I want VSCode to generate my classname based on my filename:
Filename: test-class-file.php should become: Test_Class_File
I found the following examples:

"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/[-]/_/g}" Becomes: test_class_file
"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/}" Becomes: TestClassFile

The official docs Do not mention chaining or anything like that.
There also doesn't appear to be a way to store something in a temp variable.
How can I combine these 2 into one transform/regex action?

This is much simpler:
  "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(-)|([^-]+)/${1:+_}${2:/capitalize}/g}"

Just use the captitalize transform on the non-hyphen groups.
Helpful link: VS Code snippet to capitalize each word in filename and tranform filename to Capitalize sentence with a regex and how can I transform a variable to title-case.

You can use
"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([^-])([^-]*)|(-)/${1:/upcase}${2:/downcase}${3:+_}/g}"

This will work like this:

([^-])([^-]*) - captures the first non-hyphen char into Group 1 and the rest of non-hyphen chars into Group 2
(-) - captures any -s into Group 3.

When Group 1 matches, it is turned into uppercase, Group 2 contents is turned to lower, and every - is replaced with _.

Thanks, this works! One small improvement. \.\w+$ is not needed as the var TM_FILENAME_BASE is already without file extension. All of the files I tested work.
